# Diagnosis page Error:Trying to visualize a point data using createviz in cartodb.js

Tags: carto, windshaft

I had setup the cartodb locally in my machine following this tutorial https://github.com/danseely/cartodb-install/blob/master/DEV-INSTALLATION.md

Everything is installed perfectly: I can visualize a data in my local account, but when i try to import a dataset it's showing an error.

So i created dataset with point data. When i try to visulaize it by using the createviz function in cartodb.js i can only see the basemap but my point data is not visible.

When i go to the diagnosis page (development.localhost.lan:3000/diagnosis)

I'm getting this error

CartoDB extension: error

```
    Installed version: 0.11.1
    Current supported version: 0.9.Latest version: 0.9.3
```

Windshaft: error

```
    Service url: http://localhost.lan:8181
    Full config: {"filter"=>"mapnik", "internal"=>{"protocol"=>"http", "domain"=>"localhost.lan", "port"=>"8181", "host"=>"127.0.0.1", "verifycert"=>false}, "private"=>{"protocol"=>"http", "domain"=>"localhost.lan", "port"=>"8181", "verifycert"=>false}, "public"=>{"protocol"=>"http", "domain"=>"localhost.lan", "port"=>"8181", "verifycert"=>false}}
    error fetching info: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
```

SQL API: error

```
    Service url: http://localhost.lan:8080
    Full config: {"private"=>{"protocol"=>"http", "domain"=>"localhost.lan", "endpoint"=>"/api/v1/sql", "port"=>8080}, "public"=>{"protocol"=>"http", "domain"=>"localhost.lan", "endpoint"=>"/api/v2/sql", "port"=>8080}}
    error fetching info: A JSON text must at least contain two octet
```